# Unable to download Laravel Homestead

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I am trying to download homestead. Due to poor connection it got broken in middle. When I tried again then it gave error:

> Enter your choice: 1
>   ==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.7) for provider: virtualbox
>       box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box
>   ==> box: Box download is resuming from prior download progress An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error message,
>   if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try again.
>
> HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.

When I tried to download the thing from the URL then instead of `virtualbox.box` it fetches the file `hc-download`?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the box and try to download it again from scratch?

Comment: @Railslide Yeah, by removing from vagrant/tmp.

Comment: What's the output of  `vagrant box remove --force laravel/homestead` and `vagrant box add --clean --force laravel/homestead`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this before. I renamed the hc-download to homestead-0-2-7-vb.box

And then I use `vagrant box add laravel/homestead (path to downloaded file)`

It worked